# Function parameter in str_getcsv

Tags: php, function, csv

I tried use function parameter $separator instead ";" in str_getcsv function but I got an error. Do you have any ideas what Can I do with it?
I must read a few CSV files with diffrent separators. 
Error code: Undefined variable: separator in .. number on line 59

```php
function CSV2DB($producent,$znak='',$separator,$ilosc_col) {
  $time_start = microtime(true); 
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 50000); //wydłużenie czasu wykonania
global $pdo;
$log ="";
$count = 0;
$edit_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $dane = array();
    $dir = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Prusik\\csv\\';
    //sciezka do pliku
    $real_path = $dir . $producent . '.csv';
//csv do tabeli
     $data = array_map(
       function($v)
     {
       return str_getcsv($v, ";");
    }, file($real_path));
```

Comment: Please, show us your error

Comment: what error did you got `I got an error` - is not very useful.  Also your code does not use this `I tried use function parameter $separator instead ";"`  it uses `;` hard coded.  How can we debug code that is not the code>  PS.  Fix your tabbing

Comment: We need to see what error your getting. Also as mentioned before the code you posted has ";" hard-coded. Put $separator back in its place and show us the actual code that was getting the error. Are you sure you spelled separator properly when you were originally testing? Are you sure $v is not empty? Where does $v get its value for example.